# Lumen route caching is not working

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5, lumen

When I am trying to run `php artisan route:cache` in lumen project, I am getting following error,

```
[invalid argument exception]
There is not commend defined in the 'route' namespace.
```

My route file is,

```
 $app->get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\WebController@index');
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command exists only in Laravel and in Lumen it does not. it is not needed as Lumen is anyway optimized for best performance.

Type `php artisan` to see all possible commands in Lumen.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,One more doubt regarding the routing, Is there resource routing available in lumen?

Comment: Resource routing is not available in Lumen! Lumen is a micro framework and not a full featured framework like Laravel is!

Comment: @ArjanSchouten Resource routing available in Lumen micro framework. Ex:                                                                                   
app('resourceRoute',['languages','LanguageApiController']);